# How to securely maintain user authentication through a third party API?

Tags: php, mysql, api, web-applications, authentication

I'm building a webapp that allows users to create, edit, and save documents. The database of user accounts is controlled separately and I've been provided a SOAP API that will tell me whether a given username/password is valid.

Assuming the username/password are valid, the API will give me back the following info:
• email address
• username
• login_number (unique id for the account, appears to be an auto-increment int)

I'll be storing data for my app in my own database so I'll probably be using the login_number to tie data to individual users.

My question is how I should keep track of a user once that user has successfully logged in. Storing the login_number as a cookie would work but seems like it'd be horribly insecure to me. I'm thinking something along the lines of a cookie storing some sort of random hash with a lookup table storing that hash and the associated login_number but I'm not really sure that's sufficient.

Tagged with PHP/MySQL as that's the back end I'm planning on working with, but not sure it really matters for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common case with any open authentication take Facebook oAuth 2.0 for example. Once user agrees on your terms, Facebook provides his userid, email and also a way to check, at any time when you want, whether the user is still logged-in or not.

So, there are a couple of ways:

1. **Rely on the provider**: If based on User-Id the SOAP API provides the information whether the user is logged in or not. You may just use this call before performing any task that require authentication.
2. **Build your own Authentication on top of SOAP API**: This is what you are planning to do, I guess. The approach is to use a encrypted/hashed and hard-to-recreate token. 
   The idea goes like this
   (a)As soon as user logs in create a unique token, save this token in user's session or some permanent store. May be in memcache or somewhere mapped with the userId. Basically, wherever you may retrieve this token, you know which user is associated with it.
   (b) Store this token as cookie.
   (c) Whenever you want to authenticate, use the token from cookie to match against the token saved in the user's session (or pull out the userId matching the token and match the current userId with userId pulled using token for validation).
   (d) delete cookie on logout.
    Now, there are good chance of [man-in-the middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attach with this approach. 
    One approach, and it's expensive, is that to change token at the end of each request. This does not eliminate MITM attack, but chances of attack gets fairly slim.

Hope this helps.

---

**Nonce** The idea of nonce is simple and very solid. But I am unsure it will be applicable to your case. It's basically to protect SOAP calls. AWS uses similar thing.

1. Provide client with `secretKey`.
2. Whenever cient makes a request, he has to pass a hash of current time-stamp with `secretKey` (say it `token`) and the timestamp that it has used to create the `token`.
3. Server validates the `token` by comparing `token` with the hash that the server creates using timestamp passed in header and the secretKey stored else where on server-side, may be in database as password or secretKey.
4. If the tokens match, user is allowed access else not.
5. One more thing, the server may also disbar the access if timestamp is too off from server's current timestamp.

This approach is effectively free from MITM attack, but not sure if this is best suited approach for you.

The client server dialogue looks like this

```
client ----request timestamp                           --------> server 
       <---current timestamp                           -----------'
--- {ts: timestamp, token: Hash256(timestamp, secretKey)} --> isEqual(token, hash256(ts, secretKey))
                                                              |   |
                                        Access Denied<- false/   true --> ACCESS
```

@kramthegram  thanks for reminding Nonce

Comment: The changing nonce prevents the man in the middle attack as long as you don't repeat the nonce and you change it with each request. I think changing at logout is good enough though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hashing the user number with a session based [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). Set that cookie to expire on a login timeout length(say 30 minutes). The random per session nonce will help prevent playback attacks where a malicious user could copy your cookie to gain access since each session has a time sensitive hash.