# Is it a good idea to add UTC timestamp for API authentication

Tags: php, android, ios, api, authentication

I have seen many sites such as

**Amazon** : (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) adding UTC timestamp("seconds since epoch") to HMAC for stopping replay attacks.

Many authentication tutorials and forums like [How to securely maintain user authentication through a third party API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937332/how-to-securely-maintain-user-authentication-through-a-third-party-api) are also suggesting this.

I have only one concern in this, can it cause issue when mobile apps communicate with the API, I have checked it will not cause issue on Web when communicating with API's on web with PHP.

Comment: Why do you think it might create an issue with mobile apps? Always use UTC for timestamps, and allow some margin for discrepancies between the clocks

Comment: I am not sure what will happen when user changes mobile time.

Comment: You can change the time of any client device, but why would you?

Comment: Yes , you are right, can there be any other cases where this approach might be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with Amazon S3 is:

1. their API will create a link with the timestamp
2. amazon stores this timestamp and request separately
3. you will use that link
4. amazon will check if it is not expired for given request

For you as a user has that timestamp just a informative character and you can do whatever you want with it, it doesn't matter at all. Amazon compares stored timestamp with Amazons servertime...

Comment: can you please give details of more resources this regard.

Comment: here is very good article: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/